# Updating view does not work (through binding property)

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn

my intention is update wpf Window whenever Shippers collections or any its member is modified.
Shippers collection and its modifications works fine, but view is not updated in spite of i think i set everything correctly.

Please, can someone see the reason why view is not updated correctly with Shippers collection modifications?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EnterEventTextBox.DataView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EnterEventTextBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Black"
        Title="DataView" Height="450" Width="300"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" Background="Turquoise"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="ItemsControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shippers}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" Style="{DynamicResource ItemsControlStyle1}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <WrapPanel Background="Green" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ToggleButton Height="50" Width="50" Background="Red" Content="{Binding BtnLabelShipper}" Margin="0,0,5,5" 
                                cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ShipperIsClicked($dataContext, $this.IsChecked)]">                            
                        </ToggleButton>

                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parcels}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Button Height="50" Width="50" Background="Red" Content="{Binding ParcelNumber}" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <!-- -->
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View Model:

```
public partial class DataViewModel : Screen
    {
        public DataViewModel()
        {
            Shippers.Add(new Shipper() { ParcelAmount = 5, ShipperName = "PPLppl", IsUnrolled = true});
            Shippers.Add(new Shipper() { ParcelAmount = 7, ShipperName = "DPDdpd", IsUnrolled = false });
            Shippers.Add(new Shipper() { ParcelAmount = 9, ShipperName = "GEISgeis", IsUnrolled = false });
        }

        public void ShipperIsClicked(Shipper shp, bool isChecked)
        {
            if (shp != null)
            {
                shp.IsUnrolled = isChecked;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Shippers));
            }
        }

        private List<Shipper> shippers = new List<Shipper>();
        public List<Shipper> Shippers
        {
            get { return shippers; }
            set
            {
                shippers = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Shippers);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure Shipper also implements INotifyPropertyChanged and fires the PropertyChanged event, e.g. when `IsUnrolled` changes. `NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Shippers));` is pointless in that case. Besides that, Shippers should probably be an `ObservableCollection<Shipper>`.

Comment: Yes, Observable Collection was crucial. Thank you for tips, i will implement them. I would mark your answer as solution but there is no option here.